# Connecting Alfresco using Alfresco API's

Tags: alfresco

We are working on a POC in which we need to use `Alfresco` API's to connect with Alfresco Repository and perform some `Insert/Update/Retrieve/Delete` Operation.

There are many references available on the internet which is using `cmis` API but we will not use `cmis`.

Anybody can suggest to us with some reference to use Alfresco API to perform all the crud operations including creating the connection with the repository.

Thanks,

Amit

Comment: What kind of CRUD operations like create, upload and delete files ? Do you want to use CMIS ? Java or .net or python ?

Comment: Which version of Alfresco are you targetting? (Different ones have different APIs available)

Comment: Yes (Create/upload/Delete)We do not want to use CMIS and we are on Java Platform.

Comment: We are using Alfresco 6.0

Comment: CMIS does CRUD functions out-of-the-box and has a Java client ready for you to use. Out of curiosity, why don't you want to use it?

Answer (score 3):

Have you checked the [Alfresco Public ReST API](https://docs.alfresco.com/6.0/pra/1/topics/pra-welcome.html) ?
You should also be able to explore the [swagger documentation](https://api-explorer.alfresco.com/api-explorer/) of it [here](https://api-explorer.alfresco.com/api-explorer/).

Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I'm an employee at Alfresco.

To build on Younes' answer, I would wholly recommend Alfresco's Rest API. In fact there is a WAR you can install called API Explorer that makes the API easy to look through and understand. It can even help you generate http client code for most components. You can actually play around with it a bit by checking out: https://api-explorer.alfresco.com/api-explorer/

This page tells you how to install it: https://docs.alfresco.com/6.2/concepts/dev-api-by-language-alf-rest-install-api-explorer.html

It's been around (supported anyways) since the 5.2.4 version and has access to more and more components with each new release like:

- Actions
- Activities
- Auditing
- Nodes
- People
- Queries
- Renditions
- Sites
- Versions

This is just the Core section too. There's also a full section on search, authentication and workflow. It's pretty neat and you can use it literally with just about any kind of http client/programming language (I prefer to use it often with Python Requests module). It's very easy to use. Alfresco's ADF (built with Angular mostly) makes heavy use of it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [Alfresco Content Service REST APIs](https://api-explorer.alfresco.com/api-explorer/#/nodes)  for Insert/Update/Retrieve/Delete on Nodes